How to directly access two different instance of EC2 in the frontend
I'm working on a project where I'm using Node.js in my backend and react native in my frontend with GraphQL (client and server). I am planning on running my project using an EC2 virtual machine (most likely on of the m7 instances). For certain actions in my app, I need access to an EC2 with machine learning capabilities (I'm using Python with Tensorflow).
Most of these actions deal with images, which Apollo GraphQL is not great at handling. (I need to process these images and then store them in AWS E3.) Is it possible to directly access this other EC2 instance in my frontend and avoid GraphQL as a way of sending the images?
(Note: I tried asking this question on the Software Engineering forum since I don't have any specific code that I'm asking about, but it was closed for being off topic.)

What do you mean by "access this other EC2 instance in my frontend"?

@JohnRotenstein Hi, what I meant was from the frontend could I directly (for instance with some type of a put/post request) send the images to that other virtual machine (ml instance) without having to go through the main virtual machine/server which runs my application

If your Node app has endpoints, contacting the Node EC2 from your web app front end is not a bad approach.

If you are worried about latency then yes, you could route directly. If you put API Gateway in front of your EC2 instances you can route to servers on a per-URI basis. And since these will all come from the same domain, you won't have any client-side CORS issues either.
